# Docker, maven and settings.xml

Tags: docker, configuration, maven-3

Given following simple Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8-alpine 

# Copy maven settings
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY pom.xml .

# WHY IS settings.xml HERE NOT CONSIDERED?
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn -X"]

# WHY IS settings.xml HERE NOT CONSIDERED?
#OR: RUN mvn clean install deploy
```

I copy here the `settings.xml` as suggested in the [maven's docker doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) into the image. Now, when I run the container, this will fail with: `Could not find artifact com.my.artefactory:my-parent:pom:2.0.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`
As we can see here, maven tries to resolve things from the default maven repo - despite the fact that I defined my own maven repo in the settings file.

When I remove `ENTRYPOINT ["mvn -X"]` and connect to the container `docker run --rm -it mvn-builder sh`, and then manually run `mvn -X` in the shell, it actually works! There is also the expected output

`[DEBUG] Using mirror my-mirror (https://com.my.artefactory/repository/whatever-repo/) for central (http://central).`

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the problem is actually the fact that the image I derive from `maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8-alpine` already defines an `ENTRYPOINT`.

When I run `docker run -it --rm my-image-mvn  mvn clean install deploy` it just works fine - good enough for me...

**EDIT**
But I still wonder, why does that not work with ENTRYPOINT (or RUN)?

**EDIT 2**
Ok, I finally get it, hope it will help somebody else. The maven's image uses an `ENTRYPOINT` with a shell script, which will make sure the `settings.xml` is placed into the correct directory. This happens only when you start a container instance.
In order to actually make it work for e.g. a `RUN` command, you have to do some of the work yourself.

Here is an example:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8-alpine AS maven-builder

# Since we want to execute the mvn command with RUN (and not when the container gets started),
# we have to do here some manual setup which would be made by the maven's entrypoint script
RUN mkdir -p /root/.m2 \
    && mkdir /root/.m2/repository
# Copy maven settings, containing repository configurations
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2

...

RUN mvn clean install
```

Comment: It did really helped, thanks man. I was strugling to configure the settings.xml in the proper place.

Comment: You could also specify the settings.xml to use with the `--settings` (or `-s`) parameter: `COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/` `RUN mvn --settings /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml clean install`